# Convert to LINQ lambda expression 4

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

how to convert to lambda:

```html
var source = new Item[]{
                    new Item { Key = "A", ID = 1, Text = "Hello" },
                    new Item { Key = "A", ID = 2, Text = "World" },
                    new Item { Key = "B", ID = 2, Text = "Bar" },
                    new Item { Key = "B", ID = 1, Text = "Foo" }
                };

var results = (from r in source
                           group r by r.Key.ToString() into g
                           select new
                           {
                               g.Key,
                               Data = string.Join("", g.OrderBy(s => s.ID).Select(s => s.Text))
                           });
```

It is possible to convert?

Thanks for answer

Comment: You need to do the work here yourself. As a start, note that the names usually match up. "select new { ... }" in LINQ translates to .Select(new { ... }) in code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you tell us what you've tried so far that doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
var results = source.GroupBy(r => r.Key).Select(g => new
{
    g.Key,
    Data = string.Join("", g.OrderBy(s => s.ID).Select(s => s.Text))
});
```